# What does 키재기식의 상식 대결 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

기실 세번이나 모임에 나오면서도 나는 이들이 어쩌면 통신에 존재하는 허다한 마니아 집단들처럼, 도토리 [[키재기식의]] 상식 대결이나 벌이는, 할 일 없는 속물들은 아닐까 하는 생각을 하고 있었던 것이다.

So I get that it literally  means acorn height  measurement but I don't understand what the sentence means

Answer (score 5):

Not '도토리 [[키재기식의]] 상식 대결이나 벌이는' but '[[도토리 키재기]]식의 상식 대결이나 벌이는'.

'도토리 키재기' means 'comparing the height of acorns'. Comparing the height of acorns are meaningless because all acorns are short, and the difference of height is insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

1) 도토리 키 재기 = struggling of people of low-level

2) 네가 크면, 얼마나 크다고 ? 너나 나나 도토리 키재기지.

If you are tall, how are you tall ? Difference of heights of you and me is not big and we are short.

3) If A has score 10 and B has score 20, then their score-comparing is 도토리 키재기.

If A has score 98 and B has score 99, then their score-comparing is very important, because an entrance can be determined by 1-score difference.